# How to exclude cucumber tags

Tags: java, scala, cucumber, cucumber-junit

I have a bunch of IT cases with various cucumber tags. In my main runner class I want to exclude all the scenarios which have either @one or @two. So, below are the options I tried **Option 1**

```
@CucumberOptions(tags=Array("~@one,~@two"), .....)
```

or **option 2**

```
@CucumberOptions(tags=Array("~@one","~@two").....
```

When I tried with option one, test cases tagged with @two started executing while with second option it did not.
As per cucumber documentation an OR will be maintained when tags are mentioned as `"@One,@Two"`. If this is the case why doesn't exclude work the same way i.e. the first option?

Update: This piece of code is written in scala.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I think I figured out how it works.

`@Cucumber.Options(tags = {"~@one, ~@two"})` - This translates to if '@one is not there' **OR** if '@two is not there' then execute the scenario

So all the scenarios in the below feature are executed. Because, the first scenario has tag @one but not @two. 
Similarly Second scenario has tag @two but not @one. 
Third Scenario has neither @one nor @two

```
Feature:
  @one
  Scenario: Tagged one
    Given this is the first step

  @two
  Scenario: Tagged two
    Given this is the first step

  @three
  Scenario: Tagged three
    Given this is the first step
```

To test my understanding, I updated the feature file as below. With this change, all scenarios without tags @one or @two were executed. i.e @one @three, @two @three and @three.

```
Feature:
  @one @two
  Scenario: Tagged one
    Given this is the first step

  @two @one
  Scenario: Tagged two and one
    Given this is the first step

  @one @three
  Scenario: Tagged one and three
    Given this is the first step

  @two @three
  Scenario: Tagged two and three
    Given this is the first step

  @one @two @three
  Scenario: Tagged one two and three
    Given this is the first step

  @three
  Scenario: Tagged three
    Given this is the first step
```

Now if we do an AND operation:
`@Cucumber.Options(tags = {"~@one", "~@two"})`- this means execute a scenario only when **BOTH** @one and @two are not there. Even if one of the tag is there then it will not be executed.
So as expected, only scenario with @three got executed.

Comment: I tried with similar examples on my machine and was able verify this behavior.

Comment: Also if you want to do `and` and from the cucumber command line runner you have to say something like: `--tags @a --tags @b`. For or it would be like `--tags @a,@b`

Answer (score 2):

How to exclude/ignore one Tag

*(this answer can help other users who just want to ignore one tag)*

Terminal:

```
mvn clean test -Dcucumber.filter.tags="not @one"
```

Junit:

```
@CucumberOptions(tags = "not @one")
```

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible it doesn't like the Array, maybe try:

```
@CucumberOptions(tags={"~@one,~@two"}, .....)
```

Comment: My apologies that I did not mention that the code I have in the question is in Scala

Answer (score 0):

in general there is the folowing logic behind the tagging:

AND logic is like this:

```
tags = {"@Tag1", "@Tag2"} //both tags must be present or:
tags = {"~@Tag1", "~@Tag2"} // both tags must not be present, 
//if only one is the stuff will be executed!
```

OR logic is like this:

```
tags = {"@Tag1, @Tag2"} //one of these Tags must be present or:
tags = {"~@Tag1, ~@Tag2"} //one of these Tags must not be present, the Rest will be executed!
```

But i found out, that cucumber soon will support the "or"-Operator in tagging and replace the comma+""-STUFF.., so it is easier to express the differences. It is goind to be like:

```
tags = {"@Tag1 or @Tag2"}
```

Original message from system is:

```
Support for '@tag1,@tag2' will be removed from the next release of Cucumber-JVM. Please use '@tag or @tag2' instead
```

Hope this can help in future, too. :)